# Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

While creating a new Conda env, I am getting this error and once I create an env, I can't able to run code on Pycharm, always shows various error. is it any problem while creating env? how can we solve?

```
(base) C:\Users\Ashit Debdas>conda create -n my python=3.7.0
WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'C:\Users\Ashit Debdas\anaconda3\envs\my'
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic.
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

Comment: I am finding this on Conda/Python3.10/Linux Mint 20.04 on an HP laptop, Frustrating!